# Initializers may only be declared within a type

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

func Question() {
    var questiontext : String
    var answer : Bool

    init(text: String , correctanswer: Bool ){ //error in this point : Initializers may only be declared within a type
        questiontext = text
        answer = correctanswer
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

An `init`  should be inside `class` / `struct` type not `func`

```
class Question { 
    var questiontext : String
    var answer : Bool 
    init(text: String , correctanswer: Bool ){  
        questiontext = text
        answer = correctanswer
    } 
}
```